# TypeError: users.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was working on a react project which is using map function, i am using react router dom and redux also this error is struck when i fetch users from the mongoose database,the file which throws error is Users.js, and my frames collapse, the code is given below
Users.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUsers } from '../../redux/actions/users/userActions';
import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';

const Users = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers());
  }, [dispatch]);
  const usersList = useSelector(state => state.usersList);
  const { loading, users, error } = usersList;

  console.log(users, loading, error);
  return (
    <div className='container-fluid'>
      <h1 className='text-center m-5'>List of users {users && users.length}</h1>
      <hr className='text-white' />
      <div className='row text-center justify-content-center'>
        {loading ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : (
          <>
            {users &&
              users.map(user => (
                <div className='col-lg-3' key={user._id}>
                  <div className='card'>
                    <div className='card-body'>
                      <h5 className='card-title'>{user.name}</h5>
                      <p className='card-text'>{user.email}</p>
                      <i className='far fa-address-card h2 text-info'></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

but while submitting response i am getting the following error

```
  20 | {loading ? (
  21 |   <Loading />
  22 | ) : (
> 23 |   <>
     | ^  24 |     {users &&
  25 |       users.map(user => (
  26 |         <div className='col-lg-3' key={user._id}>
```

can anyone help me sorting this?

Comment: just make sure that users is an array and not something else.

Comment: What is `usersList.users`? It would appear to have an initial value that isn't falsy, but also isn't an array. The solution is to either make it falsy (like `null`) or an array (like `[]`).

Comment: @Karan Wagh can you show the output of  `console.log(users)`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `users` object. May be its default value is defined but not with empty array (and you try to use map function), or users in selector have different (non-array) type after setting from server response.